# I can't read and print my Json file. It failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, importerror, tflearn

I am trying to create a chatbot. I created a Json file which contains some possible questions and answers. But I am trying to run the following python code to load and print the questions and answers from the Json file named "intents.json".

```
   mport nltk
   from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
   stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

   import numpy
   import tflearn
   import tensorflow
   import random
   import json

   #read json file
   with open("intents.json") as file:
   data = json.load(file)

   print(data)
```

**But I'm having the following Error... Please I need your help guys :(**

```
PS C:\Users\PRINCE\Documents\SONISOFT\Python Tutors\Python Chat Bot Tutorial\Chat-bot> python main.py             Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
import tflearn
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PRINCE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
```

above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: You need to ensure, have the latest [MSVC redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) and the Python binary is installed from official sources not from Windows marketplace. Thanks!